# groupId of maven projects hosted on GitHub

Tags: java, maven, github, sonatype

I have a open source maven project hosted on GitHub. Let's say the url is https://github.com/foo/bar.

Now I want to upload it to the Sonatype OSS Maven Repository. I checked that they have a strict rule on the groupId (https://central.sonatype.org/publish/requirements/coordinates/#supported-code-hosting-services-for-personal-groupid).

> groupId will identify your project uniquely across all projects, so we need to enforce a naming schema. It has to follow the package name rules, what means that has to be at least as a domain name you control, and you can create as many subgroups as you want. eg. org.apache.maven, org.apache.commons
> A good way to determine the granularity of the groupId is to use the project structure. That is, if the current project is a multiple module project, it should append a new identifier to the parent's groupId.
> eg. org.apache.maven, org.apache.maven.plugins, org.apache.maven.reporting

The question is that for projects hosted on GitHub, what is the proper groupId?

As user generated website has domain foo.github.io, I have at least the following two options:

- com.github.foo
- io.github.foo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a popular choice to use a groupId with the hosting site in the name. Search on http://search.maven.org for

- net.sf
- sourceforge
- googlecode
- github

While it is better to use a domain that you really own, using the hosting site in the groupId is a sensible fall-back. You should try to make sure that you choose a name that is not associated with the hosting company itself (e.g. com.google) but with the hosting site (e.g. com.googlecode), so that it is clear you are a project on the site and not a project of the underlying company.

Comment: So `io.github.foo` is better than `com.github.foo` ?

Comment: No better, but is more modern :) Use what you like more.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use your own domain in the groupId, not github.* - that implies that the project is owned by Github.

Comment: If you use com.github, I would agree. But afaik io.github is reserved for projects.

Answer (score 1):

While many `groupId`s of Maven projects are derived from the web domain, they are derived from the domain of the people who started the project - [github](http://github.com/) is just a convenient service to give other people access to your project.

So you should select an ID which is specific for you [just like all the other projects there](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=github%3a%20pom.xml).

Answer (score 0):

Another options is `foo.bar` as groupId, but groupId with `github` is also good.